# VS Code document formatter to indent multi line arguments vertically aligned to the opening bracket/brace of the argument list

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, indentation

How can I set an indentation rule such that auto indent (Format document command) should align a multi line function's params vertically to the opening bracket/brace of the argument list?

e.g.

```
export function foo(a: number,
                    b: string,
                    c: boolean) {
                                        
                    }
```

Currently it does something like:

```
export function foo(a: number,
    b: string,
    c: boolean) {
                                        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently possible at least without any extensions. The list of javascript formatting settings is available under the prefix `javascript.format` and I don't see any settings that control that behaviour.

This was raised as an issue on the VS Code GitHub repo at: [Incorrect (potentially) indentation of function arguments spanning multiple lines #13748](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13748). The issue got moved to the TypeScript GitHub repo at: [Incorrect (potentially) indentation of function arguments spanning multiple lines #11629](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11629). If you want to show support, go give a thumbs up reaction to [this comment in that thread suggesting to make the indentation style configurable by the user](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11629#issuecomment-408022747) (but if you do, please leave it at that and don't pester the maintainers with noisy "me too" comments unless you also plan to say something constructive and meaningful).

I'm also pretty sure this is a per-language-support-specific thing. For example, there's a separate issue on the vscode-cpptools extension's GitHub page: [Indent function arguments #1993](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1993)